# Rank problem in inversion of t(A) %*% A in R

Tags: matrices, linear-algebra

I need to get the inverse of the cross-product $(\mathbf{A}' \mathbf{A})$, and I run into numerical problems that don't make any sense to me. I actually need $(\mathbf{A}' \mathbf{W}^{-1} \mathbf{A})^{-1}$, where $\mathbf{W}$ is a given symmetric positive-definite weighting matrix, but here I just take the case $\mathbf{W}=\mathbf{I}$.

Here is what I have in R. The matrix whose cross-product I want to invert is "grad.hat". It's a (27, 24) matrix with rank 24. And we [know](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)#Properties) that because it has real values, its cross-product must have rank 24, and thus be non-singular. Now the following results seem to defy the laws of math: rank of the cross-product is 15, and it is thus singular. However, surprise, its eigenvalues are all strictly positive, so it should be non-singular! Some of them are pretty small though, is that the source of my problems?

```
Browse[2]> dim(grad.hat)
[1] 27 24
Browse[2]> dim(crossprod(grad.hat))
[1] 24 24
Browse[2]> qr(grad.hat)$rank
[1] 24
Browse[2]> qr(crossprod(grad.hat))$rank
[1] 15
Browse[2]> eigen(crossprod(grad.hat))$values
 [1] 6.554842e+10 6.554842e+10 6.554842e+10 3.925534e+04 3.925411e+04 3.925307e+04 2.864401e+01 1.260996e+01
 [9] 1.214270e+01 1.935087e+00 1.706200e+00 1.242853e+00 1.141820e+00 1.073751e+00 1.015352e+00 7.780677e-01
[17] 7.573530e-01 7.136721e-01 2.564850e-01 2.549935e-01 2.509688e-01 3.367800e-05 2.588893e-05 1.255226e-05
Browse[2]> solve(crossprod(grad.hat))
Error in solve.default(crossprod(grad.hat)) : 
  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 1.66296e-16
```

Using function rankMatrix from package Matrix, whose default settings are supposed to be equivalent to Matlab results, I get the following:

```
Browse[2]> rankMatrix(grad.hat)
[1] 24
attr(,"method")
[1] "tolNorm2"
attr(,"useGrad")
[1] FALSE
attr(,"tol")
[1] 5.995204e-15
Browse[2]> rankMatrix(crossprod(grad.hat))
[1] 21
attr(,"method")
[1] "tolNorm2"
attr(,"useGrad")
[1] FALSE
attr(,"tol")
[1] 5.329071e-15
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: What happens if you use `qr(crossprod(grad.hat), tol=1e-12)$rank` or some other lower tolerance? At any rate, using `solve()` is numerically not very stable (especially in these border cases). Does `tcrossprod(qr.solve(grad.hat, diag(27)))` maybe work?

Comment: Thanks! Setting the tolerance low enough yields full rank, but seems rather artificial, doesn't it? Your qr.solve method works though, could you explain it? And can I get my weighting matrix $W^{-1}$ in there?

Comment: When I try `qr(crossprod(grad.hat, qr.solve(lambda.hat, grad.hat)))$rank` I get a rank of 7 (`lambda.hat` is $\mathbf{W}$).

Comment: Posted a full answer. See if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be an issue due to $A'A$ being close to singular. When `qr()` tries to determine the rank of a matrix, a numerical tolerance is involved (by default, `tol=1e-07`) that happens to work okay for $A$ itself, but not $A'A$. Increasing the tolerance (i.e., making it smaller) may show that $A'A$ is still of full rank (but barely).

At any rate, using `solve()` to obtain the inverse is numerically unstable, especially in these border cases. As an alternative, one can use the QR-decomposition to obtain the inverse (see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition#Using_for_solution_to_linear_inverse_problems)). Both `tcrossprod(qr.solve(grad.hat, diag(27)))` and more clearly `qr.solve(crossprod(X))` should work and yield the same result.

If $W$ is diagonal, then you can use `tcrossprod(qr.solve(sqrt(W) %*% grad.hat, diag(27)))`. Otherwise, you first have to obtain the square-root of the $W$ matrix (or rather, a square-root, since it's not unique). This should do it:

```
e <- eigen(W)
V <- e$vectors
sW <- V %*% diag(sqrt(e$values)) %*% t(V)
tcrossprod(qr.solve(sW %*% grad.hat, diag(27)))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works just fine! Just to be clear, if I want $(\mathbf{A}' \mathbf{W}^{-1} \mathbf{A})^{-1}$, I would have to use `tcrossprod(qr.solve(qr.solve(sW) %*% grad.hat, diag(27)))`? And is it always better to use an identity matrix as second argument of a solve?

Comment: No, just `tcrossprod(qr.solve(sW %*% grad.hat, diag(27)))`. And the identify matrix as the second argument is not arbitrary -- if you want the inverse, then you need the identity matrix there.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's `tcrossprod(qr.solve(qr.solve(sW) %*% grad.hat, diag(27)))` for $(\mathbf{A}' \mathbf{W}^{-1} \mathbf{A})^{-1}, and some simulations in the non-singular case confirm this. But thanks a ton!

Comment: I meant for $(\mathbf{A}' \mathbf{W}^{-1} \mathbf{A})^{-1}$